# How do I determine, cross browser, if the node within a contenteditable element is empty?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

Without having to resort to a library, I would like to know **if** (not when) the content of the contenteditable element below has been deleted.

```
<span contenteditable id=foo>tell me when this string is deleted</span>
```

Comment: If. Also, I edited the example to use '<span>'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I run Linux so I can't test IE, but it works in Chrome and Firefox

```
document.getElementById("foo").onkeyup = function (event) {
    // Firefox doesn't like innerText
    var content = this.innerText || this.innerHTML;

    // this replace strips whitespace (can be removed if needed)
    if (content.replace(/\s/g, "").length === 0) {
        this.blur(); // when using an alert, the onkeyup event will fire again if you hit enter...
                     // this removes the focus beforehand
                     // (can be removed if you are not using an alert box or something similar)

        alert("content deleted");
    }
};
```

Comment: Having read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/whitespace_in_the_dom I think the regex might be more robust if it were:
    /[\t\n\r ]+/g

Answer (score 0):

```
var empty=document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]*>/g,"").replace(/ /g,"").length==0;
```

Comment: "I would like to know if the content of the editable div below has been deleted.", not: "I would like to delete the content of the editable div" ;)

Comment: @Harmen: I didn't write `=`, I wrote `==`.

Comment: @thejh, sorry, I didn't notice that. But the tricky part is to tell when you need to check this.

Comment: I think the length of innerHTML can be less than 4 and the textnode not be empty.

Answer (score 0):

There is no onchange event, but there is an onkeyup event:

```
document.getElementById('foo').onkeyup = function(){
  if(this.innerHTML.length == 0) alert('string deleted');
};
```

Comment: In Chrome, the length never reaches 0 as the 'empty' state has a '<br>' within (4) or sometimes <whitespace>

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of at the moment is to create a polling event that checks every little bit to see if the div still contains the same text.  If you know what text you're looking for, you could just use some regex (or plain string searching) to see if the string is still there.

You could listen for keydown, keypress, or keyup events, but remember to add a timeout to make sure that their last keypress has been taken into consideration, as their last press may have been the backspace key.